# Does Hybris B2B support product configuration from the PDP (product detail page)?

Tags: configuration, product, sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

In the OOTB (out of the box) B2B powertools, it looks like there is a product that can be configured using the Configure button.  But clicking on it leads to Server Error.  The button is in this screenshot.

[image: PDP Configure]

> The functionality I am trying to achieve is something like this which I saw in a C4C [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eWaGgN4Pjo) (but it's not explained in English)

[image: Product Configuration Page from C4C]

So, the concern is that, can this way of configuration be achieved in powertools OOTB?

There is plenty of documentation, but didn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration tool is part of SAP CPQ (SAP Configure, Price, and Quote for Product Configuration), now named [SAP Product Configuration](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8b3f53c38669101497c2f71cb181fbbf.html).

There are a on-premise and a Cloud version. The on-premise use a special engine to install along SAP Customer Experience (hybris).

> The latest service packs and patches for SAP CPQ Configuration Runtime Engine are available on the SAP Service Marketplace at support.sap.com/swdc under Support Packages and Patches (not under Installations & Upgrades). In the alphabetical list of products, choose letter C and then SAP CPQ PRODUCT CONFIG 3.0.

You can see how to install on-premise version [here](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8b8d342586691014b3e6cec4ab9b4c8b.html).

[image]

Above scheme from https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/bc1bdbe575964d45a34d4253f6f9d675.html shows you the extensions dependencies.

OOTB you won't have this tool installed. You need a license that includes the necessary options to use it in production.